# Is it possible to Refresh/Rerun a Function after Clicking on a Button with Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to make an **adjustCart()** function work before and after an event occurs but for it to work properly again, the function has to be refreshed after the click event occurred. The function controls the incremental buttons of the products that have been added to the cart.

For instance, after adding a few products to the cart, (in which each product has an increment or decrement qty button after being added to the cart) I should be able to increase and decrease the quantity of each product added to the cart. This works well but the problem is -

Each of the products in the cart also has a remove button.
Now when I click on the remove button of a random product in the cart, the incremental buttons of the products below the one removed do not work unless I call the adjustCart() function inside the removeCart event. Yet, calling the adjustCart() function in the remove event also has a problem because the incremental buttons are now being called twice. This means the quantity of each product is added twice after clicking on add button.

Is it possible to refresh the function when it is called during the remove event?

````
     ``` const ProductSection = () => {
      
      let inc;
      let cartValue = document.getElementsByClassName("cart-number")
      
      let productNumber = document.getElementsByClassName("bar-number");
      let tableRow = document.getElementsByClassName("table-row");
     
      let cartPrice = document.getElementsByClassName("cart-price");
      let totalPrice = 0;
    
      let createCart = document.getElementById("tbody");
    
    let products = { 
      0: {
          index: 0,
          id: 'p1',
          name: 'Samsung TV',
          image: "./Images/product1.png",
          cart: "ADD TO CART",
          price: 500000
        },
      1: {
          index: 1,
          id: 'p2',
          name: 'Pixel 4a',
          image: "./Images/product2.png",
          cart: "ADD TO CART",
          price: 250000
        },
      2: {
          index: 2,
          id: 'p3',
          name: 'PS 5',
          image: "./Images/product3.png",
          cart: "ADD TO CART",
          price: 300000
        },
      3: {
          index: 3,
          id: 'p4',
          name: 'MacBook Air',
          image: "./Images/product4.png",
          cart: "ADD TO CART",
          price: 800000
        },
      4:{
          index: 4,
          id: 'p5',
          name: 'Apple Watch',
          image: "./Images/product5.png",
          cart: "ADD TO CART",
          price: 95000
        },
      5: {
          index: 5,
          id: 'p6',
          name: 'Air Pods',
          image: "./Images/product6.png",
          cart: "ADD TO CART",
          price: 75000
        }
      }
    //Create a List of Products
    function displayProducts(){
      document.getElementsByClassName("grid-container")[0].innerHTML = 
      Object.keys(products).map(product => 
        `<figure class="product-figure">
            <div class="container">
              <img class="product-image" src="${products[product].image}" alt="${products[product].name}"/>
              <div class="overlay">
                <div class="text">
                  <p>PRICE</p>
                  <p>#${products[product].price}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <h2 class="product-header">${products[product].name}</h2>
            <button id="add-product" class="product-button" name=${products[product].index}>${products[product].cart}</button>
          </figure>`
      ).join("")
    }
    displayProducts();
    
    //Create an Html body of Products Added to Cart Section
    function cartProducts() {
      document.querySelectorAll(".product-button").forEach((item) => {
        
        inc = 0;
        inc++;
        
        item.addEventListener('click', function() {
          if(item.textContent === "ADD TO CART") {
            cartValue[0].textContent++;
            item.textContent = "Remove From Cart";
            products[item.name].cart = item.textContent;
    
            const addProduct = Object.keys(products).filter(product => 
              products[product].cart === products[item.name].cart
            )
            createCart.innerHTML = `${addProduct.map(pr => 
              `<tr class="table-row">
              <td class="table-col">${inc++}</td>
              <td>${products[pr].name}</td>
              <td class="cart-price">${products[pr].price}</td>
              <td class="adjust-cart">
                <span class="bar adjust-bar add-bar">add</span>
                <span class="bar bar-number">1</span>
                <span class="bar adjust-bar sub-bar">sub</span>
              </td>
              <td class="remove-cart" title=${products[pr].index}>Remove</td>
            </tr>`).join("")}`
          }else{
            cartValue[0].textContent--;
            item.textContent = "ADD TO CART"
            products[item.name].cart = item.textContent;
            
            const subProd = Object.keys(products).filter(product => 
                products[product].cart !== products[item.name].cart
              )
            createCart.innerHTML = `${subProd.map(pr => {
              //console.log(products[pr].name)
              return `<tr class="table-row">
              <td class="table-col" >${inc++}</td>
              <td>${products[pr].name}</td>
              <td class="cart-price">${products[pr].price}</td>
              <td class="adjust-cart">
                <span class="bar adjust-bar add-bar">add</span>
                <span class="bar bar-number">1</span>
                <span class="bar adjust-bar sub-bar">sub</span>
              </td>
              <td class="remove-cart" title=${products[pr].index}>Remove</td>
            </tr>`}).join("")}`
          }
          removeCart()
          adjustCart()
        })
      })
    }
    cartProducts()
    //Calculate and Display the Total Price of Products in Cart Section
    

    //Reveal Cart Section as a Pop up When Cart Button is Clicked.
    function revealCart() {

    document.getElementsByClassName("cart-button")[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
      
      if(cartValue[0].innerHTML !== "0") {
        document.getElementById('abc').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('empty').style.display = "none";
      }else{
        document.getElementById('abc').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('empty').style.display = "block";
      }
    })
    document.getElementById('first-close').addEventListener('click', function() {
      document.getElementById('empty').style.display = "none";
    })
    document.getElementById('second-close').addEventListener('click', function() {
      document.getElementById('abc').style.display = "none";
    })
}
revealCart()

    //Add or Subtract Products in the Cart Section.
    function adjustCart() {
      
      for (let i=0; i<tableRow.length; i++){
        console.log(productNumber[i].innerHTML)
        document.getElementsByClassName("add-bar")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
          productNumber[i].innerHTML = Number(productNumber[i].innerHTML) + products[i].price;
          cartPrice[i].innerHTML = Number(cartPrice[i].innerHTML) * 2;
          showCartPrice()
        })
        document.getElementsByClassName("sub-bar")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
          if(productNumber[i].innerHTML === "1"){
            alert("Click on the Remove button")
          }else{
            productNumber[i].innerHTML = Number(productNumber[i].innerHTML) - 1;
            cartPrice[i].innerHTML = Number(cartPrice[i].innerHTML) - products[i].price;
          }
          showCartPrice()
        })
      }
    }

    //Remove Products in the Cart Section
    function removeCart() {
    
      document.querySelectorAll(".remove-cart").forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener("click", function(){
          cartValue[0].textContent--; 
    
          inc = 0;
          inc++;
          item.parentElement.remove();
          document.querySelectorAll(".table-col").forEach(item => {
          item.innerHTML = inc++;
        })
        adjustCart()
        document.getElementsByClassName("product-button")[item.title].innerHTML = "ADD TO CART";
        products[item.title].cart = "ADD TO CART";
        showCartPrice()
      })
    })
    }
    
    }
    ProductSection() ```
````

Comment: Please don't link to your code. Place all the relevant code right here in your question.

Comment: Alright, I think that is all the relevant code needed for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The  solution  (while keeping your idea), is to remove the event listeners first.
The problem here is, that you call `addEventListener()` everytime, the function `adjustCart()` is called. That's why you stack up the events which are triggered by a click.

You would need to change your function like this:

```
function adjustCart() {
    let productNumber = document.getElementsByClassName("bar-number");
    let cartPrice = document.getElementsByClassName("cart-price");
    let tableRow = document.getElementsByClassName("table-row");

    for (let i = 0; i < tableRow.length; i++) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("add-bar")[i].onclick = null; // <-- remove all onclick events
        document
            .getElementsByClassName("add-bar")
            [i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            document.getElementsByClassName("bar-number")[i].innerHTML =
                Number(productNumber[i].innerHTML) + 1;
            document.getElementsByClassName("cart-price")[i].innerHTML =
                Number(cartPrice[i].innerHTML) * 2;
            showCartPrice();
        });
        document.getElementsByClassName("sub-bar")[i].onclick = null; // <-- remove all onclick events
        document
            .getElementsByClassName("sub-bar")
            [i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            if (productNumber[i].innerHTML === "1") {
                alert("Click on the Remove button");
            } else {
                document.getElementsByClassName("bar-number")[i].innerHTML =
                    Number(productNumber[i].innerHTML) - 1;
                document.getElementsByClassName("cart-price")[i].innerHTML =
                    Number(cartPrice[i].innerHTML) / 2;
            }
            showCartPrice();
        });
    }
}
```

What you really want to do is: Everytime a new button is created for the cart, the event should be assigend. Therefore it the best, to assign the events just when you create the buttons. This way, the events will be bound only once and you don't need to touch them again.

Your `adjustCart()` function is doing nothing else then always assign the same events to all item in the cart. You don't need that. Just assign them once, when they are created

Comment: Thanks @Michael Walter, but I still get the same error as the one in my code. 
I have added some extra code for better explanation